# How to remove elements from a list of lists where an element is repeated?

Tags: python, list, unique

I have a list of lists

```
my_list = [["a", "b", "c"],
           ["d", "f", "g"],
           ["h", "b", "i"]]
```

I want to remove all elements in `my_list` where element[1] is not unique. So the result after performing this operation is either

```
my_list = [["d", "f", "g"]]
```

or a new list also works

```
new_list = [["d", "f", "g"]]
```

My current method is:

```
from collections import Counter

y_list = []

for element in my_list:
    x, y, z = element
    y_list.append(y)

count_dict = dict(Counter(y_list))

unique_y_list = []

for y, count in count_dict.items():
    if count == 1:
        unique_y_list.append(y)
 

valid_elements = []

for element in my_list:
    x, y, z = element
    if y in unique_y_list:
        valid_elements.append(element)
```

This works but doesn't seem efficient. Help with a more pythonic way to achieve my desired result? Preserving order is not important.

Comment: What do you mean by 'where element[1] is not unique.' ?

Comment: I mean any element where index[1] of that element occurs more than once  in my_list. my_list [0] [1] == "b" ; my_list [2] [1] == "b" ; remove these elements

Comment: The only thing inefficint is how you re-construct the valid elements. Don't create *a list*, `unique_list`, and check `if y in unique_y_list`:, instead, use `if count_dict[y] == 1: valid_elements.append(element)`

Comment: also, `dict(Counter(y_list))` is unecessary. a `Counter` is a dict already

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a `Counter` of elements in the index 1, and then use it to check if each list's element at index 1 is unique:

```py
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(x[1] for x in my_list)
result = [l for l in my_list if c[l[1]] == 1]
```

Comment: This is pretty much what the OP is doing.

Comment: @Mureinik thank you, exactly what I was looking for, fewer lines of code